# How to programmatically send a emoji image to Whatsapp App on Android?

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

Whatsapp's Android documentation explains how to [send text and images as messages](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app/?lang=en) but I can't find anything about setting a new emoji image into WhatsApp.

I have downloaded a sticker/emoji creation app on my Android phone.  After creating a new memoji, it shows a "Add to WhatsApp" button.  I suspect it sends some Intent to WhatsApp, then WhatsApp would show a confirmation to the user about adding the Memoji.  Once confirmed, the memoji is added to the Whatsapp keyboard.  I haven't seen such Intent documented so want to know what Intent it may be.

Comment: Examine Logcat and see what happens when you click "Add to WhatsApp".

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StringBuilder** like this:

```
int smilingFaceUnicode = 0x1F60A; //U+1F60A

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello everyone ");
sb.append(Character.toChars(smilingFaceUnicode));
```

Result :

> Hello everyone

You can search your emoji character with unicode in the link below.
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html